# PHP How to Echo Across the Whole Page

Tags: php

I have created a skin switcher and it is working great, but the code is messy.

I save a cookie and then for some defined css classes, I append '-userDelectedColourFromTheCookie' to the end of the css class to apply it on the page.

So far, I am adding a short php line to the end of every instance of these classes in the html code and as I have said, it is working.

I would prefer to run the php code just once across the whole page and update all occurrences of an array containing the required classes to append the class as above.

I have this at the top of my page:

```
<?php
$classList = array("theme-1","theme-2","theme-3","theme-4","theme-5","theme-6","theme-7","theme-8","theme-9","theme-10","theme-hover","theme-heading","theme-drop-content","theme-container","theme-banner-text");
if ((isset($_COOKIE["Theme"])) && in_array($_COOKIE["Theme"], array("Blue","Red","Grey","Ochre","Mauve"))) echo $classList."-".strtolower($_COOKIE["Theme"]);
?>

<!DOCTYPE html>
... etc
```

I am defining an array of css classes, then reading the user colour from the cookie and appending it to the css class.

As and example, the default class might be 'theme-3' but of the user selects the blue skin, then this class becomes 'theme-3-blue' and so on.

But it's not working.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Instead of changing the class for each element, add a class to `<body>`, and check for that in the CSS.

Comment: Your trying `echo $classList` which is an array.  Which element from `$classList` do you want?

Comment: Other than that https://3v4l.org/W0VGY

Comment: @AbraCadaver - I want to add the appended class text to every element from the array that exists in the page.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't mess with the element class lists. Use CSS files to apply the colours you want.

Start with a basic CSS design file:

```
p {
   margin-left:10px
   font-size: 12pt;
 }
h1 {
   font-size: 24pt;
}
div {
    margin: 10px;
    padding 20px;
}
```

Then create CSS colour files with different colour selections:

blue.css

```
p {
   color:blue;
}
h1 {
    color: darkblue;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

red.css

```
p {
   color:red;
}
h1 {
    color: maroon;
    background-color: pink;
}
```

default.css

```
p {
   color:black;
}
h1 {
    color:white;
    background-color:black;
}
```

Then load the colour theme you want

```
<?php
if (isset($_COOKIE['theme'] && in_array($_COOKIE['theme'], ['red','blue'])) {
    $themeCSS = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="'.$_COOKIE['theme'].'.css">';
} else {
    $themeCSS = '<link rel="stylesheet" href="default.css">';
}
```

Then echo `$themeCSS` in your `<head>` just like any other `<head>` element

** I've used standard HTML elements here to illustrate, but any CSS selectors should work.

Comment: Thank you for this suggestion.  It works well.  I had previously done the same thing with Javascript but was not happy because the scripts always run at the very end of the page load, so there was always a delay while the images were loading before the script was run and the theme was applied.  Doing it this way with PHP loads the stylesheet immediately, so the delay is gone.

Answer (score 0):

Several good ways to do it.  It's a little more complicated with the array of classes but you should be able to adjust this if you need it (not sure why the syntax highlighting is wonky).

Use output buffering and replace at the end:

```
<?php
ob_start();
?>
```

---

```
<html>
<head></head>
<body>
    <div class="theme-1"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

---

```
<?php
$themes = array("Blue","Red","Grey","Ochre","Mauve");

if ((isset($_COOKIE["Theme"])) && in_array($_COOKIE["Theme"], $themes)) {
    echo preg_replace('/class="(theme-[^"]+)"/', 'class="$1-' . $_COOKIE['Theme'] . '"', ob_get_clean());
}
```

With the array of classes, just do it the same way with output buffering but replace like so:

```
$replace = array_map(function($v) { return "{$v}-{$_COOKIE['Theme']}"; }, $classList);
echo str_replace($classList, $replace, ob_get_clean());
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to change the class names inside the $classList variable by appending the selected color theme from the cookies.

You may use the **array_map** function to modify all elements of your $classList array.

```
$classList = array("theme-1","theme-2","theme-3","theme-4","theme-5","theme-6","theme-7","theme-8","theme-9","theme-10","theme-hover","theme-heading","theme-drop-content","theme-container","theme-banner-text");
$themeColor = $_COOKIE["Theme"]; // blue
$classList = array_map(function($val) use ($themeColor) { return $val.'-'.$themeColor; }, $classList);
```

Once you use the **array_map** function, all elements of the $classList array will be appended with the "-blue".

You can execute and see the output here
[http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6051282e00be1eb7bb7e6a086de20bbcfe9bcc9f](https://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/6051282e00be1eb7bb7e6a086de20bbcfe9bcc9f)